# Python function doesn't return any values

Tags: python, function

It works with certain values (e.g "100 12 2"), but fails at "102 12 2" for some reason.
Checked both on Windows and MacOS with different python versions, results are the same and are not affected by setup.

```py
from math import floor

s, x, y = 102, 12, 2

def calc(s, x, y):
    q = 0
    if x > y:
        while s - (s / x) > 0:
            q += s / x
            q1 = s / x
            s = s - (s / x) * x
            s += q1 * y
        return floor(q)
    else:
        return 'Inf'

if type(calc(s, x, y)) is int:
    print(calc(s, x, y))
else:
    print('Inf')
```

Comment: Please update your question with a selection of inputs and outputs showing which work and which do not. Also explain what the calculation is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing the zero in the condition with a small number, such as `1e-16`:

```py
from math import floor

s, x, y = 102, 12, 2

def calc(s, x, y):
    q = 0
    if x > y:
        while s - (s / x) > 1e-16:
            q += s / x
            q1 = s / x
            s = s - (s / x) * x
            s += q1 * y
        return floor(q)
    else:
        return float('Inf')

print(calc(s, x, y)) # 10
```

The reason of doing so is that the sequence `s - s/x` does not become exactly zero; it only gets arbitrarily close to zero. (Even if exact zero is guaranteed algebraically, float is subject to inherent imprecision, so you need some threshold anyways.)

Comment: You are a life saver. Could you please explain why it keeps iterating through `while` and gets stuck instead of returning `floor(q)`?